# What is a "feature" in Getis-Ord G* hot spot analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, features, spatial-statistics, hot-spot

From the [official site](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/h-how-hot-spot-analysis-getis-ord-gi-spatial-stati.htm), it says "The Hot Spot Analysis tool calculates the Getis-Ord Gi* statistic (pronounced G-i-star) for each feature in a dataset" and "xj is the attribute value for feature j".

Say the entire map is divided into 100 smaller grid units, but only 50 of these 100 units have an input value. Do I have 100 or 50 "features"? For the units that don't have an input value, do they also go through the G* statistics? If so, does it mean it automatically assumes the value of 0?

Comment: Please note that you are referencing ArcGIS Pro in your question which otherwise seems to be about the earlier ArcGIS 10.x for Desktop architecture.  The documentation may or may not be suitable for what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Each row in your table will a feature.

So you have 100 features. How many rows are in your attribute table? This is your number of features in almost all cases.

If they have 0 they will count as 0.
If they have no value it is the same as them not existing.

So you have 100 features.
50 features with a valid value for G*